# OS X Video Driver corruption

Tags: macbook-pro, video, hdmi

I have a mid-2010 Macbook Pro with 10.9.4.  I've been using it with a Seiki 39" 4K TV as a monitor for about a month now with no problems.  (This is using an UltraAV MDP to HDMI Active Adapter cable.) For the first time yesterday I selected "1080p" as the resolution in Display Preferences to see what it looked like.  Immediately after going to 1080p resolution, the list of resolutions went blank.  I could click (or option-click) on the scaled circle, and there would be a delay of a few seconds, then I'd see a list of resolutions flash up, and then go away.  Based on what I later figured out, I think if I had tried to click one of those selections when they flashed up, I would have gotten out of 1080p mode.  But I did something else, trying to reset the display preferences to a normal state. (I don't remember what exactly)

From then on, the Mac seems to think it's talking to a dumb TV.  It only lets me select 1080p, 720p, and two other resolutions.  Additionally I get a slider for "Underscan" which tells me it thinks it's talking to a TV in some sort of "TV-mode".  I don't see the full set of resolutions going up to 4k that I was seeing before.  Here is what I've tried with no joy:

- reinstall jumbo update for 10.9.4 (no help)
- updating firmware on the TV
- reseting TV to factory standard
- logging in as another user (still see 1080p)
- Resetting the PRAM
- logging in in Safe Mode (this works!)

I'd like to remove/reset/review all the non-user files that are different or new since the base OS was installed (counting updates).

The only other thing I can think of is to reinstall the whole machine.

Any ideas short of that?

Update:
Option-clicking the "Scaled" choice enabled about 10 additional choices, which are all smaller than 1080p.  But still no 4k choices, and I still get a slider for Underscan, so it's still in 1080p mode.

I tried the SwitchResX app, and it might have had a way to help, but I wasn't able to figure out how to do what I wanted.  The normal default operations didn't seem to allow the resolution I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to get my screen working.

- Remove /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist
- Remove /Users/yourusername/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.windowserver.*
- Reset PRAM

This didn't immediately fix the problem, but I tried rebooting into safe mode to make sure that still worked.  I switched resolutions around in safe mode.  I rebooted into regular mode.

Eventually I saw a resolution option I hadn't seen before.  It was something like "740 x 1200 (HiDPI mode)."  I selected that, and then the mode flipped away from "dumb 1080p" and it gave me a the range of high resolutions I had before.

It seems that HiDPI is Apple's name for a "retina display" driver.

So now I think the OS must have some sort of binary flag to puts you in HiDPI mode.  My problem was that the flag got turned off, and I didn't have an easy way to turn it back on again.  If I'd known that earlier I would have tried setting a properties flag like:

sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist DisplayResolutionEnabled -bool true

I found that described here:
http://cocoamanifest.net/articles/2013/01/turn-on-hidpi-retina-mode-on-an-ordinary-mac.html

I got my display working again, but if I needed to dig deeper into it, I would learn more about HiDPI mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on "Scaled" while holding the <kbd>⌥</kbd>  key.

Regular click:
[image: Display settings pane]

<kbd>⌥</kbd> + click:
[image]

Comment: That definitely helped me with my fiddling.

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems with a *MBA11 macOS Sierra(10.12)* and *DELL U2715H*. It was using the 2560x1440 resolution but it was always applying underscan (image was not using the whole panel).

I installed *SwitchResX 4.6.0* and then finally, after digging for a few minutes through all those options, I found what I wanted: 
**SwitchResX Preferences > Menus > Menu Extra - Display overscan/underscan (checkbox)**

Now when I click the icon I can see the slider to adjust image size!
The app has many other funcionalities and, at this moment, costs 14€.